# using functions on values of common key names

Tags: python, function, dictionary, nested

If I define the following dictionary, can I use functions such as `max(), min(), numpy.mean(), numpy.median()` to calculate statistics on the values of the keys 'avalue' for of all of the keys of adict (i.e. for key1 through key3) without first appending the values to a seperate iterable object?

```
adict = {'key1':{'achar':'a','avalue':1},'key2':{'achar':'b','avalue':2},'key3':{'achar':c,'avalue':3}}
```

Comment: Why don't you want a separate iterable object?  If you use a generator expression, it should be about as efficient as anything else you could come up with.

Comment: E.g. `max(adict[k]['avalue'] for k in adict.iterkeys())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written below step by step , Hope you may got your answer

```
>>> [ x for x in adict.keys() ]
['key3', 'key2', 'key1']
>>> [ adict[x] for x in adict.keys() ]
[{'achar': 'c', 'avalue': 3}, {'achar': 'b', 'avalue': 2}, {'achar': 'a', 'avalue': 1}]
>>> [ adict[x]['avalue'] for x in adict.keys() ]
[3, 2, 1]
>>> sum([ adict[x]['avalue'] for x in adict.keys() ])
6
```

Comment: Just a small point that `.keys()` here is redundant - the default iterator of dictionaries returns keys - `for x in adict.keys()` is the same as `for x in adict`.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks happydave and expecially Shawn.  I see how it works